# I have a data set of optimal values after simulations, How can I find if this dataset follows a specific pattern or any relation exists?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, correlation, data-analysis, pattern-recognition

In the simulation I am conducting, I have a set of triangles and I select the optimal triangle based on my metric. After every simulation, I obtain an optimal triangle and I note down the lengths of its three sides. So I conducted this simulation a large number of times and noted the lengths of the three sides of the optimal triangle. Now I want to see if there is any pattern which these three sides follow or if there is any relationship among these three sides, or even between two sides.
For example, the names of the three sides are D1, D2, and DX, a relationship can be something like , D1=D2=Dx or D2=2 times Dx, etc. (simple examples, it may have a little complex relation).
I have seen that D2 and DX have a close correlation, how can I use this to relate it with D1 OR what conclusion can I draw from it? How can I analyze these three variables together? Whether I can do something like D1 Vs (D2 and DX)?

The dataset looks like this: (but having large number of data)

D1 D2 DX

3.3 3.0 3

1.12 0.83 1

4.4 6.44 6

2.5 11.9 15

0.79 2.19 3

3.81 9.63 12

2.4 4.9 7

2.56 13.2 13

1.97 5.26 5

4.50 3.68 4

4.72 5.21 6

0.89 4.10 5

1.78 5.89 8

3.2 7.54 12

3.18 2.20 4

Comment: can anyone help me solve this?